# Appbar Button icon image seems not correct in Window 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I created an appbar button using BitMapIcon. Below is the code

```
<AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Label="AppBarButton" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Foreground="White">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/work.png"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Where `work.png` is the button image. But appbar button image seems different that of the original work image. See the Images

[image]    [image]

The second image is the original icon of `40 x 40` size image & i put background as black for display purpose `[work.png]`. 
What to do for displaying the button icon as correct as in the original icon ? Or what is the reason for this mis match?

> Will the appbar button allow semi-transparent icon images?

Comment: It seems to me like it's decoding it at the wrong size and the aliasing is what's causing the issues. Is it possible to get that Icon as a Path? According to Tim Heuer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/12a75cc9-2a03-47c0-ad9a-40ce15aec4ab/sizes-of-a-bitmapicon), they are finding some very non-optimal instances with BitmapIcons, especially finely detailed ones like you have there.

Comment: @NateDiamond Yea. At last i used Path Data from the svg image & i got it correct. But for some svg images there includes more than one Path Data. How we can use it ?

Comment: So, the `PathIcon`'s `Data` property is a `Geometry`, of which a subclass is the nifty `GeometryGroup` class. This will allow you to create multiple `PathGeometry`s as children.

Comment: At last i replaced png image by path.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found setting the height and width to that of the png stopped it.
**Note:** 40x40 seems too large for the circle.

```
<AppBarButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Label="AppBarButton" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" Foreground="White">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/work.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into something similar.  It appears to be an issue with the Alpha values on your original PNG.  Normally, an Alpha value attached to a white pixel can give you a kind of greyscale image against a dark background that provides more detail than just a monochrome image.  That is, your original PNG may be composed of all white pixels but has Alpha values that are being corrupted by the BitmapImage control.  I've found two options.  You can either go to the original PNG and remove the pixels that have alpha values that are not 0 or 255, or you can re-template the AppBarButton to use the Image control instead of the BitmapIcon.  It is my opinion that the BitmapIcon is brain-damaged and have opted for the latter, which is not too terrible as the original template can be found at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481531.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help, I created Path data for the image and used it in the PathIcon